# Retrieving interested grid data from E-OBS grid datasets in netCDF file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, netcdf

Recently I am working with geospatial data in R, I faced this problem. I downloaded `E-OBS` gridded data from [`E-OBS` grid data](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php), I am interested in `0.25` degree grid data of land surface temperature and precipitation for **France** only, but `E-OBS` grid data is conducted on whole europe and all measurement in daily level. However, those `E-OBS` grid data in `netCDF` format (`.nc` file), after decompressing those grid data, it is almost `1GB` size. I used `ncdf4` package to read and process them in R.

Here is what I did in R:

```
library(ncdf4)
dat <- ncdf4::nc_open("~/rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc/rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc")
```

here is `E-OBS` grid data information down below:

```
> dat
File ~/rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc/rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        short rr[longitude,latitude,time]   
            long_name: rainfall
            units: mm
            standard_name: thickness_of_rainfall_amount
            _FillValue: -9999
            scale_factor: 0.100000001490116

     3 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:464
            long_name: Longitude values
            units: degrees_east
            standard_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:201
            long_name: Latitude values
            units: degrees_north
            standard_name: latitude
        time  Size:5479   *** is unlimited ***
            long_name: Time in days
            units: days since 1950-01-01 00:00
            standard_name: time

    5 global attributes:
        Ensembles_ECAD: 17.0
        Conventions: CF-1.4
        References: http://www.ecad.eu\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/ensembles.php\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/Haylock_et_al_2008.pdf
        history: Wed Apr  4 11:37:33 2018: ncks -a -d time,10957,16435 rr_0.25deg_regular_1.nc rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc
Wed Apr  4 11:36:14 2018: ncks -a --mk_rec_dmn time rr_0.25deg_regular.nc rr_0.25deg_regular_1.nc
        NCO: 4.6.7
```

here is the code I want to access its metadata:

```
dat$dim$longitude$vals
dat$dim$latitude$vals
dat$dim$time$vals
lon = ncvar_get(dat, varid = "longitude")
lat = ncvar_get(dat, varid = "latitude")
```

but when I hit this code `precip = ncvar_get(dat, varid = "rr")`, Rstudio raised memory error down below:

```
> precip = ncvar_get(dat, varid = "rr")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Gb
```

I intend to read those grid data and extract all grid that belongs to France. It is not an ordinary task for me because it is my very first time to work with geospatial data. I learned `ArcGis` and tried another way to read those grid data in `ArcGis Descktop` (version: `ArcGis desktop 10.4.1`). So I used some of `ArcGis` tool down below:

from `Multidimension Tool.tbx` -> `Make NetCDF Raster Layer`, load `.nc` file and make raster. here is the screenshot down below:

[image].

My goal is to retrieve all grid data of France from original `E-OBS` grid data. Since R raised memory problem, I tried to find way to read chosen `E-OBS` grid data in `ArcGis` and export its attribute table data and work with in R later on.

To do this, I also tried like this:

from `Multidimension Tool.tbx` -> `Make NetCDF Table view`, to see its attribute table of those grid data in `ArcGis`, but it returned an empty table.

I tried to read and process those `E-OBS` grid data both in `R` and `ArcGis`, but I couldn't get all grid data of France.

How can I pull out all grid data of one specific country?

I also tried conversion toolbox in `ArcGIS` down below:

from `Conversion Tools.tbx` -> `From Raster` -> `Raster to ASCII`, but exported `ASCII` file, I have respective precipitation observation, but I lost its respective geocoordinate of the grid node.

**Desired output**:

My goal is to extract interested grid raster in `ASCII` format file because I want those extract raster in vector data. I want a format something like this in `ASCII` file:

```
-33.750  77.250   -34.8   -38.6   -31.2   -29.8   -18.8   -12.1    -9.7    -8.8   -15.8   -24.9   -35.4   -38.7
 -33.750  76.750   -34.3   -38.2   -30.8   -29.5   -18.8   -12.2    -9.9    -8.9   -15.6   -25.0   -35.0   -38.9
 -33.750  76.250   -34.7   -38.3   -31.4   -29.9   -19.7   -12.9   -10.7    -9.5   -16.0   -25.9   -35.5   -39.8
 -33.750  75.750   -34.7   -38.2   -31.5   -29.9   -20.1   -13.1   -11.1    -9.8   -15.8   -26.2   -35.5   -40.3
 -33.750  75.250   -34.5   -37.9   -31.2   -29.6   -19.9   -12.9   -10.8    -9.4   -15.0   -25.8   -35.2   -40.3
 -33.750  74.750   -33.9   -37.3   -30.3   -28.7   -19.0   -12.2   -10.2    -8.7   -14.0   -24.8   -34.4   -40.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the raster and ncdf4 R packages in conjugation. With both of these packages added, read the nc file using the `raster::stack` or `raster::brick` functions. This will keep everything memory safe as well. If there is any transposition that needs to happen, which is sometimes the case with the NetCDF format, there are some functions in raster for flipping the raster(s).

add libraries

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(R.utils)
library(maptools)
```

Here we download the data, unzip it and create a raster stack. You should set your working directory using `setwd()` so you know where everything is going.

```
url = "https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc.gz"
download.file(url, basename(url))
gunzip(basename(url))
rname <- list.files(getwd(), "nc$")
( r <- stack(rname[1]) )
```

To subset the data you can use crop with a defined extent. I pulled the extent of France from the "wrld_simpl" dataset included with the maptools package.

```
data(wrld_simpl) 
france <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "France",]
e <- extent(france)
  plot(r[[20]])
    plot(e,add=TRUE)
    plot(france,add=TRUE)
```

Here is where we crop the entire raster stack to the defined extent.

```
r <- crop(r, e)
plot(r[[20]])
  plot(e,add=TRUE)
  plot(france,add=TRUE)
```

Now that the data is subset, we can write a more friendly compressed format (LZW geoTiff).

```
writeRaster(r, "France_rr_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994.tif", 
            options="COMPRESS=LZW", overwrite=TRUE)
```

You could also write out a flat file format but, I highly recommend against this. This subset is quite small with only 201 rows and 464 columns (93,264 unique coordinate pairs). It however contains 2557 layers resulting in matrix with 238,476,048 values. If the intent is attempting to analyze this date in something like excel, this is just not tractable. The easiest way to format the data with coordinates and then write to a flat file so to coerce to an sp class object, add the coordinates to the data slot and then write the data.frame associated with the object.

```
r <- as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  r@data <- data.frame(coordinates(r), r@data) 
    str(r@data)

write.csv(r@data, "climate_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please be weary of asking more than one question in a post, it is a surefire way to get your question put on hold. I do not know what you mean by "accessing its metadata". This should be a document on the source website. What information do you need in the metadata that would accomplish the goals set forth in your spatial data processing? You could always use the ncdf4 package to read the header of the data to get general information regarding the raster stack.

Comment: I intend to keep missing values in their original grid, and I did `reclassify(tg1980, cbind(NA, -999))`, but I have a memory problem in R? How can I resolve this issue? Thank you