# Extracting exact land coverage raster from TIFF format raster using R?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, land-cover

I have land coverage raster data that downloaded from JRC data catalogue ([JRC website](http://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dataset/jrc-luisa-corine-land-cover-refined-2006) and [JRC land coverage data download link](https://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/LUISA/PrimaryOutput/Europe/REF-2014/JRC_LUISA_Input_Corine_land_cover_2006_r_ref_2014.zip)), where data file like shapefiles at a very high degree of resolution, with information of land/soil coverage, for example, information on agricultural land coverage, information about mountain, city coverage and so on. I want to extract all information on agricultural and city land coverage only for Germany and render them in my final output as `csv` or `xlsx` format.

However, I tried to read those data in R by using `raster::stack` function and I intend to crop the raster of only Germany. I got some idea from `SO` community ([useful post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280683/any-efficient-workaround-to-retrieve-interested-grid-data-from-e-obs-grid-datase)), Using Jeffrey Evans' solution, here is runnable R code down below:

```
url = "https://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/LUISA/PrimaryOutput/Europe/REF-2014/JRC_LUISA_Input_Corine_land_cover_2006_r_ref_2014.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url))
gunzip(basename(url))    # got some problem to unzip the file in R; better to use decompress the file in local site
tifDat <- list.files(getwd(), "tif$")     # tif file was located in two nested folder
land_cover = raster::stack(tifDat[1])
```

I plotted this `tif` format raster in R down below:

```
plot(land_cover)
```

[image]

My goal is I want to crop this raster only for land coverage of Germany, so I did approximate projection in R, here is the possible R code I could give it try down below:

```
germany_territory <- readOGR("germany_landCover",layer="germany_landCover")     # read Germany NUTS3 level polygon (by district level)
proj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84  +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj_raster_landcover <- projectRaster(land_cover, crs =  proj)

germany_landCover_city <- extract(x = proj_raster_landcover,                         y = germany_territory)
```

but these don't work for me, so I also tried something like this down below:

```
data(wrld_simpl)
germany <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "Germany",]
ex_deu <- extent(raster::area(land_cover))
germany_land <- crop(land_cover, ex_deu)
```

still can't achieve what I want.

**desired output**:

in cropped raster, I want a plot something like this down below:

[image]

I want to extract all information on agricultural and city land coverage only for Germany and render them in my final output as `csv` or `xlsx` format.

How can I easily deal with `TIFF` format raster in R?

How can I correctly crop the land coverage for Germany?

Any way to make this happen easily?

How can I correct my implementation on above?

Any more thoughts?

Comment: I don't recommend you to project raster. Is better to project shapefile to raster CRS.

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thanks for your help. For extracted raster grid, I want to extract all information on agricultural and city land coverage only for Germany in tabular data (`csv` or `xlsx`).  How can I make this extraction easily in R?

Comment: @aldo_tapia you mean something like this: as.data.frame(germany_land, xy=TRUE) ? I intend extract all information of agricultural and city land coverage in `csv` or `xlsx`. Could you correct me please? How can I get extraction that I specified above? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, convert raster to data.frame and then select only values related to desired classes (check LUISA_legend.xlsx) with something like `df[df$value %in% c(1,2,3....),]` and write it in a .csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned you in commentaries, project shapefile:

```
data(wrld_simpl)
germany <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "Germany",]
germany <- spTransform(germany, CRSobj = land_cover@crs)
germany_land <- crop(land_cover, germany)

plot(germany_land)
plot(germany, add=T)
```

[image]

You can also mask pixels outside Germany with `germany_land <- mask(crop(land_cover, germany), germany)`, but with `wrld_simpl` data is not recommended (is a very coarse scale).

Comment: Use `as.data.frame(germany_land)`, you can add `xy = TRUE` as argument to get coordinates